# AES Encryption from integers to integers

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am using AES encryption algorithm in java to encrypt my database values..My encryption function returns encrypted value as String but the columns of type "Int" fails to store such string values which is quite logical..Is there a way to encrypt the integers as integers (numerical values)?  Thankyou.

Comment: One possible hack is to just convert the strings to ints, but I don't think that's a good enough solution...

Comment: "My encryption function returns encrypted value as String" - let me ask the obvious... Why are you returning a `String` when you don't want or need it?

Comment: What I should I do then? how my encryption function is going to recognize what type of input it is manipulating at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

Plain AES returns an array of bytes.  You can store this as an array of bytes, a Base64 text string or as a `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger(AESByteArray);
```

It is very unlikely that the 128 bit, or larger, AES result will fit into a 32 bit Java `int`.

If you want 32 bit input and 32 bit output, so everything fits into a Java `int`, then either write your own 32 bit [Feistel cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher), or use [Hasty Pudding Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher), which can be set for any bit size you require.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting integer into integer is FPE (format preserving encryption). FPE does not change data type or data length.
Here is a reason why databases implementing FPE only for character data, never for int.
AES 128 will encrypt 128-bit block. Which is 16 bytes.
If you want to encrypt 64 or 32 bit integer(4 or 8 byte values), you still have to encrypt 16 byte block. This problem can be solved by adding 8 (or 12) bytes to int32 or int64 values. This creates issue - if added bytes are always 0, you create huge weakness in encryption, as your data set is severely limited. It can be used for brute force attack on AES etc. In turn, this can be solved by filing with cryptographically strong random number added 8 or 12 bytes (that also creates a weakness, as most likely your random genertor is not strong enough). When decrypting, you can purge extra added bytes and extract only 4 or 8 bytes our of 16 bytes.
Still, life is not perfect. AES encryption does not change size of block, it always produces 16 bytes. You can encrypt your int into 16 bytes, but database can store only 8 bytes for int.
Unless you will store data in binary(16) column. But that is not an integer, and you are asking for integer.
In theory, numeric(38) is taking 16 bytes. In some databases it is possible to set 16 bytes to arbitrary value and then extract. I have not seen it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can always encode your string in an integer, however it could be a large integer.

If you can't afford large integer, you can encode it in multiple small integers.

If you can afford neither large integer nor multiple integers, maybe you can't do it well anyway, using a block cipher in ECB mode is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the output of the encryption from string to binary, and then from binary to a decimal integer.